# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when not on localhost

Tags: c#, iis

I have a web API hosted on a server. Also, I have an angular website that uses this API to perform transactions. So, my website is constantly communicating with the web API.

when I run my website on the host server (using localhost instead of IP address) it works just fine, but if I use the IP address instead of localhost, then I have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

Also, when I try to access my website outside the host server using the IP address obviously, then I have the same error:

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://IPADDRESS' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Is there any configuration on IIS am I missing? Because on API web.config code I have the following:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I'd really appreciate any help on this.